# How to extend a character on the maximal torus to the borel subgroup

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Given a complex Lie group $G$ and a maximal torus $T$ with associated Borel subgroup $B$ and a character $\lambda : T \to U(1)$ what is the canonical extension to the Borel subgroup?

The only thing I can think of is to lift the character to the Cartan subgroup $\lambda:\mathfrak{h}\to i\mathbb{R}$ then we can extend this trivially to the Borel subalgebra and exponentiate to get a character for the Borel subgroup. However this is trivial on the off-diagonal elements which strikes me as incorrect.

Comment: That's the way to do it, I think. I'm not sure about the Lie group side, but on the algebraic group side at least you can get a projection $p:B\to T$ with a unipotent kernel $U$. So you can just pull back a character of $T$ to a character of $B$.

Comment: Yea, it's the only invariant way I can think of. The two ways give the same answer, so it's probably the "canonical" choice. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a refrence for that? I'm actually dealing with loop groups and things are a little trickier.

Comment: Afraid not. In the cases I am familiar with we can always select $B$ to consist of triangular matrices, and $T$ to consist of diagonal matrices, and in that case it is kinda trivial that characters of $B$ are extensions of those of $T$.